# I have need a condition for <jdoc:include type="component" />

Tags: php, joomla

I have need condition to showing component as like module position:

Comment: A condition for what?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible using a tag. Then you should make it as a module.

You could try [Components Anywhere](https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/componentsanywhere)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
<?php if ($somecondition == true) : ?>
  <jdoc:include type=“component” />
<?php endif ; ?>
```

If you want a more precise (ie better) answer, you need to be more explicit in your post.